# Can we refer to a JavaScript inside the jar file of a Maven dependency?

Tags: javascript, java, maven, spring-mvc, netbeans-8

I am developing a Spring MVC web application with Apache Tiles. I downloaded some JavaScript libraries such as [JQuery](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars/jquery/2.1.4) using `pom.xml` dependency entries. My question is can I refer to the scripts inside the `jar` in my tiles configuration? If yes, how do I add it? If I give the entire path to the `js` file in the `jar` and will it be resolved?

```
<tiles-definitions>  
    <definition name="base.definition"  
                template="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout.jsp">  
        <put-attribute name="title" value="" />  
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/header.jsp" />  
        <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/menu.jsp" />  
        <put-attribute name="body" value="" />  
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/footer.jsp" />
        <put-list-attribute name="javascripts">
            <add-attribute value="<CAN THIS BE A LOCATION TO JAR??>" />
        </put-list-attribute>
    <definition>
    <!--More stuff-->
</tiles-definitions>
```

Example scenario:
I downloaded datatables-1.9.4-2.jar and the maven build put's it under **\WEB-INF\lib**. Within the jar the javascript I want is **\META-INF\resources\webjars\datatables\1.9.4\media\js\jquery.dataTables.min.js** In this situation what would be my resource mapping and how do I refer to it in add-attribute element?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by defining a resource mapping in Spring MVC:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="classpath:/scripts"/>
```

And then access it as follows:

```
<add-attribute value="/js/myscript.js"/>
```

Also, since you're using webjars, I've quoted a relevant part of the [Spring Framework Reference Documentation, 22.16.9 Serving of Resources](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources):

> Webjars are also supported with `WebJarsResourceResolver`, which is automatically registered when the `"org.webjars:webjars-locator"` library is on classpath. This resolver allows the resource chain to resolve version agnostic libraries from HTTP GET requests `"GET /jquery/jquery.min.js"` will return resource `"/jquery/1.2.0/jquery.min.js"`.

Comment: I am still unable to get this working. Could you please elaborate on this based on my update with a specific scenario?